# what to `co_return` when I don't need to return anything?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I have a specific use case:

In my library, [concurrencpp](https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp), I want to implement the function `make_exceptional_lazy_result` which is basically like the C# method `Task.FromException`.

Inside the implementation of this function, I will always throw an exception, I will never `co_return` a valid object.

My current implementation looks like this:

```cpp
template<class type, class exception_type>
lazy_result<type> make_exceptional_lazy_result(exception_type exception) {
    throw exception;
    co_return *static_cast<type*>(std::malloc(sizeof(type)));
}
```

I'm grossed by the `malloc` hack - In one hand, I have to `co_return` something, on the other hand, the program will never actually reach this line.

Can I do better? I'm worried about returning a reference to an uninitialized local memory (I don't know if according to the language it's ok).

What other options can I do here that look better? Note that `type` is not necessarily default-constructable, so returning a `type{}` is not an option.

Comment: What forces you to `co_return` something? The compiler? Does adding  `[[noreturn]]` help?

Comment: [`[dcl.fct.def.coroutine]/1`](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine) "A function is a coroutine if its function-body encloses a coroutine-return-statement ([stmt.return.coroutine]), an await-expression ([expr.await]), or a yield-expression ([expr.yield]). The parameter-declaration-clause of the coroutine shall not terminate with an ellipsis that is not part of a parameter-declaration.". You need indeed co_return something if you don't co_await or co_yied.

Comment: also, [[noreturn]] doesn't allow you to not return something if the function doesn't return void. noreturn is more about compiler optimizations than allowing you to not return values when you have to.

Comment: Not true. A program is not ill-formed if a function doesn't have a return statement, it exhibits UB if and only if the execution actually reaches the end of a function body without retuning. Exception to main().

Comment: Why do you need this to be a coroutine, specifically?

Comment: I can do something like `co_return non_coro<type>()` but then what would I do in `non_coro`?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but why not just `co_return;` as you would `return;` when you have nothing to return?

Comment: I believe you can simply `return *static_cast<type*>(null);` which is... not really notably better than `malloc`

Comment: @MooingDuck you're dereferencing a null pointer. this code is UB.

Comment: @DavidHaim it would be UB if it was ever executed, but the line of code is never actually executed.

Comment: Some other libraries start with a `result_holder` with methods `set_result` and `set_exception`, and then a task is a reference to a `result_holder`, and a coroutine is syntactic sugar that converts `co_return` to `set_result` and `throw` to `set_exception`. In this model, `make_from_exception` constructs the `result_holder`, calls `set_exception`, and constructs a task from the `result_holder`. (This is probably too big a change for your library, which has `lazy_result` really care that it has a `coroutine_handle`.)

Comment: @RaymondChen I wonder if those libraries manage to get the HALO right, if a task is just a reference to a variant-like context. you really need to store the caller handle somewhere (not an implicit criticism here, just plain curiosity..)

Comment: Good point. I think a lot of these libraries predate HALO, or at least predate widespread reliable implementations of HALO. (Indeed, we still may not be there.)

Comment: `co_return *static_cast<type*>(nullptr);` and NOLINT this if necessary and add necessary comments to calm down future maintainers of this code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own awaitable type which throws the exception when `co_await`ed.

```
template<class type, class exception_type>
lazy_result<type> make_exceptional_lazy_result(exception_type exception) {
    struct awaitable {
        exception_type exception;
        bool await_ready() { return true; }
        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h)
        {}
        void await_resume() 
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    };
    co_await awaitable{ exception };
}
```

Comment: You should have `await_ready()` return `true` and throw from `await_resume()`. This avoids a suspension entirely, and avoids the [weird corner case in the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.await#5.1.3) regarding throwing from `await_suspend()` bypassing `await_resume()`.

Comment: strangely it works! I was sure that if the coroutine returns something, you should `co_return` something so that `return_value/return_void` will kick in. surprisingly it's not mandatory, but also see my answer - your solution can be simplified greatly.

Answer (score 3):

I went with @Caleth solution, only simplified:

```cpp
    template<class type, class exception_type>
    lazy_result<type> make_exceptional_lazy_result(exception_type exception) {
        throw exception;
        co_await std::suspend_never {};
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a function (OK, a coroutine) that can produce a `type`, so use it:

```cpp
template<class type, class exception_type>
lazy_result<type> make_exceptional_lazy_result(exception_type exception) {
    throw exception;
    co_return co_await make_exceptional_lazy_result<type>(exception);
}
```

Comment: it's also a clever trick